# refocusing on element with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, accessibility

i have a quiz on my page which is basically an h1 for the questions and 4 buttons in a list.

for accessibility i have aria-label for each button and when the user click on a wrong answer i'm adding 'incorrect answer' for the aria-label. to help the user understand he clicked on a wrong answer i want to refocus on the button so the user will know that this is incorrect.

my problem is that if the focus is already at the buttons, the screen reader doesn't 'reread' this button.

```
<h1>this is a question</h1>
<ul>
  <li><button id="answer_a" aria-label="answer a">this is answer a</button></li>
  <li><button id="answer_b" aria-label="answer b">this is answer b</button></li>
  <li><button id="answer_c" aria-label="answer c">this is answer c</button></li>
  <li><button id="answer_d" aria-label="answer d">this is answer d</button></li>
</ul>

$('#answer_a').on('click', function(){
  $(this).attr('aria-label', 'incorrect_answer').focus();
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/koL51nxu/

Comment: You are missing an `'` after the  `click` event. Also, you question seems unclear at least to me. Can you please demonstrate your problem in a fiddle so I can help? Now you have the click event attached only to the first button, which is a bit missleading.

Comment: i added jsfiddle. 
i'll try to clear my question: i'm using voiceover to make my quiz accessible, when the user focus on a button, the voice over reads the aria-label. when he click on the wrong answer, the aria-label changed but the voice over doesn't read the new aria-label until i'll focus out and back in from the button.

Comment: i dont understand what effect do u want..

Comment: using ChromeVox screen reader it seems to work fine, im not sure what the issue is.

Comment: `aria-label` overrides the button's text value. You do not want to do that. Consider just appending the text "incorrect answer" to the button text itself. Then consider making the entire area an ARIA Live Region so it will announce when a text value changes. No scripting necessary for the live region.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `disabled` attribute  for this.

```js
$('#answer_a').on('click', function(){
  $(this).attr('aria-label', 'incorrect_answer');
 $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>this is a question</h1>
<ul>
  <li><button id="answer_a" aria-label="answer a">this is answer a</button></li>
  <li><button id="answer_b" aria-label="answer b">this is answer b</button></li>
  <li><button id="answer_c" aria-label="answer c">this is answer c</button></li>
  <li><button id="answer_d" aria-label="answer d">this is answer d</button></li>
</ul>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/koL51nxu/1/)

Changing function `$('#answer_a')` to `$('ul li button')` will reduce your code. So that no no need to write the code again and again for each buttons -- [example](https://jsfiddle.net/koL51nxu/2/)

Comment: Why would the OP disable the button?

Answer (score 0):

Using `blur()` before the refocus helped me.